# Converting mysql query to laravel query

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

How I can convert mysql query to laravel query?
this is the query

```
SELECT p.*, 
    IF(p.id = wish.product_id,1,0) AS status
FROM products as p LEFT JOIN `wishlists` as wish ON wish.product_id = p.id and product_id AND wish.user_id = 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:

```
$result = \DB::table('products as p')
    ->select(\DB::raw('IF(p.id = wish.product_id,1,0) AS status'))
    ->leftJoin('wishlists as wish', function ($join) {
        $join->on('wish.product_id', '=', 'p.id and product_id')
        $join->on('wish.user_id', '=', \DB::raw(1))
    })
    ->get();
```